# Create a function that returns day of the week by accessing an array of strings

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to pass an integer to a function that then references a specific string in a string array.  E.g. function receives 1 and outputs "Monday", receives 2 and outputs "Tuesday" etc.  My file compiles without an error but not output is returned.  Any advice?

Yes, I'm very much a beginning but slowly chugging along.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

std::string DayName(int a);
int main()
{
int a;
printf("enter a number between 1 and 7\n");
(void)scanf("%d", &a);
DayName(a);
return 0;
}

std::string DayName(int a)
{
std::string days[7] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday"};
std::string day = days[-1+a];

return day;


}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Do you want to *print* the day or *return* the day?

Comment: You must use the return value of `DayName()`.

Comment: Also, ask yourself: What line of my code prints the results of `DayName` to the screen?

Comment: Unrelated: Consider giving `a` a name that describes what the variable contains and represents. For a small function like the one you have, one doesn't have to look far away to determine what `a` is for, but it's something that will become a significant problem when functions get longer and more complicated. Plus I see mistakes where someone mixed up two single-letter variables all the time. Not a day goes by on SO without at least one question that devolves to `for (int j = 0; j < n; i++)`

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for the helpful resources.  It's like that first article was written for me!  After reading, I have a better high level understanding of how debugging works but the actual implementation and understanding of warnings/errors is still foreign to me.

Comment: @NathanOliver does "return day;" not print the value of DayName() to the screen?  I know semantically that "return" is different from "print" but should return print DayName() to the console?

Comment: `return` tells the compiler what value the function returns to the calling scope, so you can write code like `int foo() { return 42; } int bar = foo();`.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you are simply ignoring the return value of the `DayName()` function.  You are not printing it out anywhere, which is why you are not seeing it.

You are also not validating the input is in the range of acceptable values. And you are using C-style I/O instead of C++-style I/O.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string DayName(int day);

int main()
{
    int day;
    std::cout << "enter a number between 1 and 7\n";
    std::cout << DayName(day);
    return 0;
}

std::string DayName(int day)
{
    static const std::string days[7] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    if (day >= 1 && day <= 7)
        return days[day-1];
    return "invalid";
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/mknVmE)

Alternatively, have `DayName()` throw an exception if it receives bad input:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

std::string DayName(int day);

int main()
{
    int day;
    std::cout << "enter a number between 1 and 7\n";
    std::cin >> day;
    try {
        std::cout << DayName(day);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}

std::string DayName(int day)
{
    static const std::string days[7] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    if (day < 1 || day > 7) throw std::out_of_range("Input must be 1..7");
    return days[day-1];
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/b5vwGr)

Alternative, just have `main()` do all of the validation before calling `DayName()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

std::string DayName(int day);

int main()
{
    int day;
    do {
        std::cout << "enter a number between 1 and 7\n";
        if (std::cin >> day) {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 7) {
                std::cout << DayName(day);
                break;
            }
            std::cout << "invalid, try again" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cout << "Bad input, try again" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}

std::string DayName(int day)
{
    static const std::string days[7] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    return days[day-1];
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/oNPXmv)

Comment: There is a major (relatively speaking) design issue in your code: who is responsible for validation of the input? How does `main()` know that valid days are `a number between 1 and 7`? And if it does - why doesn't it validate that input? You need a single source of truth :)

Comment: Good range check.

Comment: Ideally, `DayName()` could just `throw` an exception on bad input (ie, `std::out_of_range`), and then `main()` can `catch` it. I have updated my answer with more examples.